# Download file without disabling selinux

Tags: selinux

I am developing a site in PHP on Linux Server where I need to download a file from Windows Server to Linux Machine. I can do it with Some Changes in SeLinux or setting some properties on it, i.e.:

```
% setsebool -P httpd_disable_trans=1
```

But our client refuses to compromise any security for this functionality. So we need to find any other workarounds. What else can we do?

Comment: How do you intend to download the file? What method will you use?

Comment: Right. You need to know (and tell us) how you are fetching this file.

Comment: Refuses to compromise any security and runs a PHP application might be mutually exclusive.

Comment: i used code below if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY))
  {
   echo "successfully written to $local_file\n";
 } 
else 
 {
  echo "Not Downloaded";
 }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they will accept a policy extension for SELinux to allow the web server to do certain kinds of operations against a particular file or directory.   To create a custom policy there is a tool called *audit2allow* which can help you generate the policy you need.   There is an example of creating a custom SELinux policy module at:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-d8db97e538d95b1bc5e54fc5a9ddb0c953e9a969

If you do this make sure the process is well documented because it's the kind of thing that can get broken on a new deployment or on an update and you want to make sure it's not missed during those kinds of activities.